# How to assign multi dimentional array from a variable

Tags: php

```
$a[0][1]=1;
$a[0][5][1]=2;
$a[0][5][2]=3;
print_r($a);
```

following code produces output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
     (
        [1] => 1
        [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
         )

      )

  )
```

when I do this

```
    $a[0][1]=1;
    $a[0][5][1]=2;        
    $x='[0][5][2]';
    $a{$x}=3;        
    print_r($a);
```

It outputs

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [1] => 1
        [5] => Array
            (
                [1] => 2
            )

    )

[[0][5][2]] => 3
)
```

But I want the same output as the first one.
My array indexes come from a variable and are assigned to $a;
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using `eval` function.Basically I avoid `eval` function but did not find any other way.Here is the solution may be it helps other

```
    $a[0][1]=1;
    $a[0][5][1]=2;
    $x='[0][5][2]';
    eval('$a'.$x.'=3;');
    print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be one solution,

```
echo '<pre>';
$a[0][1]=1;
$a[0][5][1]=2;
$a[0][5][2]=3;
print_r($a);

foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    $new_array[$k]=$v;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: **Welcome to stackoverflow!** Answers like this will likely be voted down or flagged for removal. It would be beneficial for you to add some comments, explanations, reasons etc for why your code does what the question asker wants - like this it doesn't mean much to anyone :)

Comment: what is this answer?Its not related with the question.